# Assistance with bubble chart size

Tags: r

For some context I am trying to create a bubble chart to show the effects the voice the participant hears and the familiarity of the imagery has on the commitment to conversing water. I have a bubble chart where the y axis is the  level of commitment (1-5) and the x is the level of familiarity (1-5). My plan is to make the colours of the points different based one the voice ( adult or child).

My issue is I am trying to make the size of the points represent how frequent that spot in the graph shows up. For example if (4,4) shows up way more than (1,2) then it will be bigger.
I’m hoping someone can help me figure out how to code for the size to reflect this frequency.

I tried:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=familiar_place,y=commit3)) + 
   geom_point(aes(size=freqency(x=familiar_place, y=commit3))
```

This gave me the points but not the sizes I wanted.

Comment: Could you add some simple code that creates data functionally similar to `dd`? If you add that, you'll have a "reproducible example" which helps others answer your question quickly and correctly.

Comment: Use `dplyr` to add a column with the counts, `dd = dd %>% add_count(familiar_place, commit3, name = "frequency")`. Now you have a frequency column you can map size to.